# Passing C++ vector into file writer

Tags: java, c++, file

I am translating C++ program into Java. There's a piece of code that writes a BMP file. And I cannot understand `fwrite(&outPixels[0], infoHeader.biSizeImage, 1, file);` line. How does it write the entire BMP-file if it only takes the 0th element of vector (this line not in any loop)?

```
typedef std::array<uint8, 3> TPixelBGRU8;

std::vector<TPixelBGRU8> outPixels;
outPixels.resize(c_numPixels);

for (size_t i = 0; i < c_numPixels; ++i) {
    const TPixelRGBF32& src = g_pixels[i];
    TPixelBGRU8& dest = outPixels[i];

    dest[0] = uint8(Clamp(correctedPixel[2] * 255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f));
    dest[1] = uint8(Clamp(correctedPixel[1] * 255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f));
    dest[2] = uint8(Clamp(correctedPixel[0] * 255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f));
}

//
// setting a header info
//

FILE *file;
fopen_s(&file, fileName, "wb");
fwrite(&outPixels[0], infoHeader.biSizeImage, 1, file);
```

This is what I did:

```
// Vector is my own class like array<uint8, 3>
List<Vector> outPixel = new ArrayList<>(numPixels);

for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
    Vector src = pixels.get(i);
    Vector dest = outPixel.get(i);

    dest.setX((int) clamp(correctedPixel.getZ() * 255.0, 0.0, 255.0));
    dest.setY((int) clamp(correctedPixel.getY() * 255.0, 0.0, 255.0));
    dest.setZ((int) clamp(correctedPixel.getX() * 255.0, 0.0, 255.0));
}

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, 
                             BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);

// I suppose I did it wrong:
for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++) {
        img.setRGB(i, j, (int) outPixel.get(i * j));
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't write the entire BMP file, only the BITMAPINFOHEADER.

Comment: This `outPixels[0]` gives you first element, but this `&outPixels[0]` gives you address of first element, when you know address of first byte and the entire size of buffer by one call `fwrite` you can write the whole file (I mean content of BMP image, not its header, you didn't show the code which does it).

Comment: Changing to `fwrite(outPixels.data(), infoHeader.biSizeImage, 1, file)` would probably make things a lot more clear.

Comment: @rafix07 So we just pass the pointer to the array. I got it. Thank you

Comment: I wonder if values in `std::vector` have warranty to be tightly packed?

Comment: I'm not going to answer, because I can't say how this applies to the Java side of things, but to clear things up, `fwrite()` does not take a single char, that is, `outPixels[0]`. It takes a **pointer** to a char, or `&outPixels[0]` (the address of `outPixels[0]`). Because the data is stored sequentially (I think this is guaranteed for `std::vector`) `fwrite()` can access all the data even if it only knows the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&outPixels[0]` is a worse way to say `outPixels.data()`.  It is a pointer to the contents of the `vector`'s buffer.